# How to integrate CLIPS with MFC(VS2012) using dll method？

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll, mfc, clips

I am a beginner of CLIPS, I want to build an expert system with CLIPS, making the user interface with VC++ MFC at the same time. My development environment is VS2012. I find some tutorials through the Internet about VC6.0, but it doesn't work with VS2012. IS somebody kind enough to give me a specific guide about how to integrate CLIPS with MFC(VS2012) using dll method？(Maybe it is because I can not find the right clips.dll)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Windows projects for building a DLL can be downloaded from the CLIPS website at SourceForge (https://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsrules/). These were created using newer versions of Visual Studio, but you might be able to load them in an older version. Instructions for building the DLL are in Section 11 of the CLIPS Advanced Programming Guide.

Comment: Thanks for your reply first. I know the CLIPS website at SourceForge, and I have already  successfully compiled the projects in the Projects\Examples_MVC_2010 directory according  to the instructions in Section 11 of the CLIPS Advanced Programming Guide. Also, I can  find CLIPSDynamic32.dll, CLIPSDynamic64.dll, CLIPSWrapper32.lib and CLIPSWrapper64.lib  in the Projects\Libraries directory. But I still don't know how to integrate CLIPS with  MFC.

Comment: I don't know how to utilze .dll file and .lib file in my MFC project. I refer some  guides about how to integrate CLIPS with MFC on VC 6.0. In addition to include clips.dll  and clips.lib, it also includes rsvarcol.h, Rsvarcol.cpp, clipsmfc.h and clipsmfc.cpp.  Is it necessary to make the same configuration as VC 6.0, or is there other  configuration methods in VS2012?

Comment: I haven't attempted to integrate CLIPS with MFC, just .NET